# Inject Angular Constants in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have converted my first angular factory to TypeScript in my project. I'm now trying to bring in the constants from a new typescript file.

Here is the typescript file that will eventually hold more than one constant value

```
module app.config {
     export class Constants {
         static get Default(): any {
             return {
                 apiServer: 'http://localhost/MyApplication'
             }
         }

     }

     angular
         .module('app');
 }
```

Here is the new TypeScript file where I'm trying to pull in the value of `apiServer` that used to be in a `constants.config.js` file

```
module app.services {
    interface IStoreFactory {
        apiServer: string;
    }

    var constant = new app.config.Constants.Default();

    export class StoreFactory implements IStoreFactory {

        static $inject = ['$http', '$log']
        constructor(private $http, $log) {
        }

        apiServer = constant.apiServer;

        getRegisters() {
            return this.$http.get(this.apiServer + 'stores/1/registers');
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('app.services')
        .service('storeFactory', StoreFactory);
 }
```

When I hard coded the value of `apiServer` in this service it worked fine. I'm getting the error that it:

> cannot read property of 'Constants' of undefined.

What do I need to do to the `app.config` file to make it accessible in the `app.services` file?

*Side note: Also it seems odd that there is a blank `controller` I'm sure that isn't being used correctly.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues.

#### I. syntax

The first is how to consume the above `Constant` declaration. There is a fully [working adjusted example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20app.config%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Constants%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20get%20Default()%3A%20any%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apiServer%3A%20'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMyApplication'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20angular%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.module('app')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amodule%20app.services%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IStoreFactory%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apiServer%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20wrong%20statement%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fvar%20constant%20%3D%20new%20app.config.Constants.Default()%3B%0A%09%2F%2F%20Constants%20is%20a%20property%20not%20method%2C%20and%20is%20NOT%20instance%20member%0A%20%20%20%20var%20constant%20%3D%20app.config.Constants.Default%3B%0A%09%0A%09%2F%2F%20just%20to%20be%20able%20to%20run%20this%20(click%20Run%20on%20the%20top-right)%0A%09var%20div%20%3D%20document.createElement(%22DIV%22)%3B%0A%09div.innerText%20%3D%20constant.apiServer%0A%09document.body.appendChild(div)%3B%09%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20StoreFactory%20implements%20IStoreFactory%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20%24inject%20%3D%20%5B'%24http'%2C%20'%24log'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20%24http%2C%20%24log)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apiServer%20%3D%20constant.apiServer%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getRegisters()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.%24http.get(this.apiServer%20%2B%20'stores%2F1%2Fregisters')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20angular%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20.module('app.services')%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20.service('storeFactory'%2C%20StoreFactory)%3B%0A%7D%0A%20) *(click run in top right corner to see the result)*

The most important is that we cannot use this:

```
var constant = new app.config.Constants.Default();
```

because we work with static getter. The syntax must be

```
var constant = app.config.Constants.Default;
```

complete example:

```
module app.config {
     export class Constants {
         static get Default(): any {
             return {
                 apiServer: 'http://localhost/MyApplication'
             }
         }
     }
//     angular...
}

module app.services {
    interface IStoreFactory {
        apiServer: string;
    }

    // wrong statement
    //var constant = new app.config.Constants.Default();
    // Constants is a property not method, and is NOT instance member
    var constant = app.config.Constants.Default;

    // just to be able to run this (click Run on the top-right)
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.innerText = constant.apiServer
    document.body.appendChild(div); 

    export class StoreFactory implements IStoreFactory {

        static $inject = ['$http', '$log']
        constructor(private $http, $log) {
        }    
        apiServer = constant.apiServer;    
        getRegisters() {
            return this.$http.get(this.apiServer + 'stores/1/registers');
        }
    }    
//    angular...
}
```

II. order of scripts loaded into page

Here is the [broken example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0A%0Amodule%20app.services%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IStoreFactory%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apiServer%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09var%20constant%20%3D%20app.config.Constants.Default%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09catch(ex)%7B%0A%09%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20just%20to%20be%20able%20to%20run%20this%20(click%20Run%20on%20the%20top-right)%0A%09%20%20%20%20var%20div%20%3D%20document.createElement(%22DIV%22)%3B%0A%09%20%20%20%20div.innerText%20%3D%20ex%3B%0A%09%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(div)%3B%0A%09%7D%09%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20StoreFactory%20implements%20IStoreFactory%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20%24inject%20%3D%20%5B'%24http'%2C%20'%24log'%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20%24http%2C%20%24log)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apiServer%20%3D%20constant.apiServer%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getRegisters()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.%24http.get(this.apiServer%20%2B%20'stores%2F1%2Fregisters')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20angular%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20.module('app.services')%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20.service('storeFactory'%2C%20StoreFactory)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Amodule%20app.config%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Constants%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20get%20Default()%3A%20any%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apiServer%3A%20'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMyApplication'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20angular%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.module('app')%3B%0A%7D), which when run - will return this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of undefined

The reason is - we must load all the related stuff in correct order. The below case shows that app.config is declared too late:

```
module app.services {
    interface IStoreFactory {
        apiServer: string;
    }
    try {
        var constant = app.config.Constants.Default;
    }
    catch(ex){
        // just to be able to run this (click Run on the top-right)
        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        div.innerText = ex;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }   

    export class StoreFactory implements IStoreFactory {

        static $inject = ['$http', '$log']
        constructor(private $http, $log) {
        }

        apiServer = constant.apiServer;

        getRegisters() {
            return this.$http.get(this.apiServer + 'stores/1/registers');
        }
    }    
//    angular...
}    
// TOO late
module app.config {
     export class Constants {
         static get Default(): any {
             return {
                 apiServer: 'http://localhost/MyApplication'
             }
         }
     }
//     angular...
}
```

Comment: Great to see it helped ;) Enjoy the combination angular and Typescript

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting the error that it cannot read property of 'Constants' of undefined

A common problem with namespaces (`module` keyword) and using `out` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Fix : use external modules and a build tool like webpack / browserify.

Comment: would you need to build the entire application after every change?

Comment: also, I'm not using `out` as far as I can tell