# How to inject constants into other modules in angular typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In angular1, we define constants in this fashion,

```
angular.module('taskApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'angular-loading-bar',
  'ngMessages',
])
.constant('url', {
   BASE: 'http://localhost:3222',
   BASE_API: 'http://localhost:3222/v1'
});
```

then I can inject it into any module I want like so,

```
Auth.$inject = ['$http', 'url'];

function Auth($http, url)
```

Now using typescript, I'd like to do the same, I've seen this approach: [Inject Angular Constants in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009248/inject-angular-constants-in-typescript), which seems to be okay, but not the approach i'm looking for.

From my research

```
  static $inject = ["$resource", "url"];
  constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, private url: ng.IModule)
```

I'm using IModule, because it is the only hint from angular's tsd file

```
/**
 * Register a constant service, such as a string, a number, an array, an object or a function, with the $injector. Unlike value it can be injected into a module configuration function (see config) and it cannot be overridden by an Angular decorator.
 *
 * @param name The name of the constant.
 * @param value The constant value.
 */
constant(name: string, value: any): IModule;
constant(object: Object): IModule;
```

but can't find right property to retrieve my variables

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to define an interface that describes the constant.

```js
interface URL_CONSTANTS {
   BASE: string,
   BASE_API: string
}
```

Then you'd be able to use that as the type for the injected constant.

```js
static $inject = ["$resource", "url"];
constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, private url: URL_CONSTANTS)
```